# Recommended library for getting 2d coordinates of head movement

Tags: osx

My target platform is Mac OS X, but I'm looking for a library that will give me a 2D coordinate of someone's head, via the built in webcam. My requirements are that it be near real time if not real time, give me a 2d screen coordinate I can write out to a log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of options for face detection software: http://www.facedetection.com/facedetection/software.htm

The first thing that came to mind is using OpenCV:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection